# How do I install a CakePHP plugin?

Tags: cakephp, plugins

More easy questions - this time, how do I install a CakePHP plugin? I get that I take the plugin folder and put it in the, well, the `plugins` directory.

so

```
/app
    /plugins
        /what is this?
```

And I ask this, because I just downloaded a plugin - here:
http://milesj.me/blog/read/changelog-forum-2.3

And the name of the folder that everything is in is `milesj-cake-forum-29a0699`

This doesn't appear to be a good plugin name... is there some place that lists or describes what the plugin should be called? I know i know, I'm going to try it out without the 29stuff, but I like things to be silky smooth, not "trial and error".

Yes, I am a terrible programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the plugin's [documentation](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum), they refer to models as `Forum.Profile` for example which suggests that the plugins should be installed in `APP/plugins/forum` as that's where the CakePHP autoloader will look unless instructed otherwise ([section 2](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/forum#user-setup)).

Answer (score 0):

for example fb plugin ; Load the plugin in your app/Config/bootstrap.php file:

```
//app/Config/bootstrap.php
CakePlugin::load('Facebook');
```

You can use all or some of the Facebook plugin as you see fit. At the very least you will probably want to use the Facebook Helper

```
public $helpers = array('Facebook.Facebook');
```